# How to save the results of a computation happing inside loop with openSCAD?

Tags: arrays, list, list-comprehension, openscad

When I computer something inside a loop, how I can use it later?

Comment: Given your question I would say: You can't. You have to transform the loop into a recursion and use functions. But you also tagged it list-comprehension. So did you mean: How to create a list through a for loop?

Comment: List comprehension is part of the answer. The tag should not be there. It’s possible to do it with list comprehension.

Comment: Still not clear what your question actually is. Can you give an example of what you calculate and what result you expect?

Comment: Please take a look at the answer. It answered my question. Thanks for making comments here but my problem is solved (the green mark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save results with the help of list comprehensions.

```
values = [0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16];
result = [ for(i = [0 : len(values) - 1]) [i, values[i]] ];
echo(result);
```

Check out [the manual](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/List_Comprehensions) for more information.